# How to post login data using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to post login data (email, password, ip address, date) to a file (all.txt) using Javascript?

I have done extensive research on Stackoverflow and other platforms, and tried many implementations. Please, can you assist with my below code, and point me to the right direction?

```
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

function validatePass(){
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    if (password == "cm"){
        alert('Yeah, you are in!')}
    else{
        alert('Give it another shot')}
    }

    $('#enter').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/all.txt",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function() {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
});

</script> </head>

<form id="enter" action="http://google.com" onsubmit="return (this.password.value==='cm')?true:false;">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">

    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" style="width: 225px; border: 0px solid #CDCDCD; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 1em; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center;" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'email';}" onfocus="if(this.value == 'email') {this.value = '';}" value="email">
    <p>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" style="width: 225px; border: 0px solid #CDCDCD; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 1em; background-color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center;" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'password';}" onfocus="if(this.value == 'password') {this.value = '';}" value="password">
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="log" name="log" onclick="validatePass();" style="margin: 40px 40px 40px 90px; color: #ca0000; border: 0px; background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0); font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 1em;" >

</form>
```

Comment: "it's tough" is not a useful question. What problem are you having?

Comment: You shouldn't be checking the password in Javascript, that should be done on the server.

Comment: You can't post to a text file. `POST` needs to submit the data to a script that runs on the server. The script can write to a file.

Comment: Thank you Barmar! I did it as proposed. I did it through the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#enter').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "**/validateUser**",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function() {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
```

Instead of calling .txt in url, you can call a web method or action method from server side. In that method you can validate your userId and password and return success or failure.

If you are using .net MVC you can create one action method in server side.

Comment: That very much worked also to my case; after a lot of study. Thank you Suyesh.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP has no concept of files. When you POST to a URL, you are sending some data (in this case a querystring generated from the form) to a server and indicating what the data is for in the URL. It is up to the server-side code to figure out how to handle your request (to do something based on the URL and data you provided). I would suggest opening your browser's network log to see what request data is actually getting sent.

Comment: Obviously when I made this inquiry I was not aware of your valid comments. I took them into consideration when studying for the solution. Much appreciated csander.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the XMLHttpRequest object as follows:

```
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
xhr.send(someStuff);
```